# How to successfully parse images from within content:encoded tags using SAX?

Tags: image, feed, saxparser

I am a trying to parse and display images from a feed that has the imgage URL inside  tags. An example is this:

*Note>> http://someImage.jpg is not a real image link, this is just an example. This is what I have done so far.

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {
    chars = new StringBuilder();

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded")) {
        if (!atts.getValue("src").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            feedStr.setImgLink(atts.getValue("src").toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "inside if " + feedStr.getImgLink());
        } else {
            feedStr.setImgLink("");
            Log.d(TAG, feedStr.getImgLink());
        }       
    }       
}
```

I believe this part of my programming needs to be tweaked. First, when qName is equal to "content:encoded"  the parsing stops. The application just runs endlessly and displays nothing. Second, if I change that initial if to anything that qName cannot equal like "purplebunny" everything works perfect, except there will be no images. What am I missing? Am I using atts.getValue properly? I have used log to see what comes up in ImgLink and it is null always.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `content:encoded` data in a String. Then you can extract image by this library [Jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org)

**Example**:

Suppose `content:encoded` raw data stored in `Description` variable.

```
 Document doc =  Jsoup.parse(Description);
 Element image =doc.select("img").first();
 String url = image.absUrl("src");
```